# api authentication in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, authentication, restful-authentication

Currently I have an rails 3 application which uses devise plugin for website authentication. But now I'll be adding an iPhone app as well so I will be exposing the api calls to the client device (iPhone). How would I implement auth module so that iPhone client can authenticate to the rails site and access some api?

Should I be creating a oauth provider, token base auth or simple http auth works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this situation, HTTP Basic authentication would work fine. If you'd like it to be more secure, you could create an OAuth provider and create your own implementation of [Twitter xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) to make it more user friendly. Essentially, you'd create an API call that would accept a username and password and then return an OAuth request token for that user. You'd store that request token on the iPhone and use it to authenticate subsequent requests.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of how a request in ruby code would go using the token?

Comment: OAuth is a pretty complex topic so I'm simplifying this a lot, but essentially during the initial OAuth connection, you would generate an access token and store it in your database along with which user it belongs to. When you make a request to your API, you would provide the access token. Then, your service could look up who owns the access token and authenticate/authorize accordingly. Look up Ruby OAuth Provider libraries.